# I am getting The method '[]' was called on null error in my app in streambuilder [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

Edit  :- Actually I solved the issue by changing the !snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty to snapshot.data.data() != null
I found that as i was trying to migrate my project to FlutterFire with new documentation some things didn't show error but they didn't work also. But after reading documentation I was able to resolve all the issues.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot>#8fcb4):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

It is showing error in debug console for this file and it used to work and i didn't change anything but it is showing nosuchmethoderror in streambuilder

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:skype_clone/models/call.dart';
import 'package:skype_clone/provider/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:skype_clone/resources/call_methods.dart';
import 'package:skype_clone/screens/callscreens/pickup/pickup_screen.dart';

class PickupLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget scaffold;
  final CallMethods callMethods = CallMethods();

  PickupLayout({
    @required this.scaffold,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

    return (userProvider != null && userProvider.getUser != null)
        ? StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: callMethods.callStream(uid: userProvider.getUser.uid),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.data != null) {
                Call call = Call.fromMap(snapshot.data.data());

                if (!call.hasDialled) {
                  return PickupScreen(call: call);
                }
              }
              return scaffold;
            },
          )
        : Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:skype_clone/models/call.dart';
import 'package:skype_clone/provider/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:skype_clone/resources/call_methods.dart';
import 'package:skype_clone/screens/callscreens/pickup/pickup_screen.dart';

class PickupLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget scaffold;
  final CallMethods callMethods = CallMethods();

  PickupLayout({
    @required this.scaffold,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

    return (userProvider != null && userProvider.getUser != null)
        ? StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: callMethods.callStream(uid: userProvider.getUser.uid),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) {
                Call call = Call.fromMap(snapshot.data.data());

                if (!call.hasDialled) {
                  return PickupScreen(call: call);
                }
              }
              return scaffold;
            },
          )
        : Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved the issue by changing the !snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty to snapshot.data.data() != null
I found that as i was trying to migrate my project to FlutterFire with new documentation some things didn't show error but they didn't work also. But after reading documentation I was able to resolve all the issues.